# How to place markings on the lines in a tikz lattice diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have a tikz diagram of a diamond lattice (say, of subgroups of a group).  How can I place markings on the two opposite sides of this diamond?  These markings would look similar to the equal to symbols we usually place on the sides of congruent triangles.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,auto]
\node (AcapB) at (1,1) {$A \cap B$};
\node (A) at (0,2) {$A$};
\node (B) at (2,2) {$B$};
\node (G) at (1,3) {$G$};

\path[-]
(AcapB) edge (A)
(AcapB) edge (B)
(A) edge (G)
(B) edge (G)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,auto]
\node (AcapB) at (1,1) {$A \cap B$};
\node (A) at (0,2) {$A$};
\node (B) at (2,2) {$B$};
\node (G) at (1,3) {$G$};

\path[-]
(AcapB) edge node[midway,sloped, rotate=90,anchor=center] {$=$}(A) 
(AcapB) edge node[midway,sloped, rotate=90,anchor=center] {$=$} (B)
(A) edge node[midway,sloped, rotate=90,anchor=center] {$=$} (G)
(B) edge node[midway,sloped, rotate=90,anchor=center] {$=$} (G)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can define a style too:

```
\tikzset{mymark/.style={midway,sloped, rotate=90,anchor=center}
    }
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{mymark/.style={midway,sloped, rotate=90,anchor=center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,auto]
\node (AcapB) at (1,1) {$A \cap B$};
\node (A) at (0,2) {$A$};
\node (B) at (2,2) {$B$};
\node (G) at (1,3) {$G$};

\path[-]
(AcapB) edge node[mymark] {$=$}(A) 
(AcapB) edge node[mymark] {$=$} (B)
(A) edge node[mymark] {$=$} (G)
(B) edge node[mymark] {$=$} (G)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks just for fun!

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\nointerlineskip
$
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2cm,colsep=2cm]
    & G\\
A & & B\\
& A\cap B
\end{psmatrix}
\psset{nodesep=3pt,nrot=:U}
\ncline{1,2}{2,1}\ncput{\|}
\ncline{1,2}{2,3}\ncput{\|}
\ncline{3,2}{2,1}\ncput{\|}
\ncline{3,2}{2,3}\ncput{\|}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Save more keystrokes

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\def\X#1#2{\ncline{#1}{#2}\ncput{\|}}

\begin{document}
\nointerlineskip
$
\psmatrix[rowsep=2,colsep=2]
    & G\\
A & & B\\
& A\cap B
\endpsmatrix
\psset{nodesep=3pt,nrot=:U}
\X{1,2}{2,1}\X{1,2}{2,3}\X{3,2}{2,1}\X{3,2}{2,3}
$
\end{document}
```